# mgcv: gam.check() low p-value but not enough variable combinations to increase basis functions k

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have a similar issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115927/gam-check-mgcv-low-p-values-in-basis-check-results) but with the difference that I cannot increase the k-value without getting the error:

```
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom
```

I am trying to model count data of an observed species with multiple covariates in the GAM such as the moon (percentage of illumination), cloud cover (percentage), survey duration (minutes) etc.

```
> gam_Sp1 <- gam(ln~s(LunarPerc, k=20) + s(Duration, k=30) + s(Clouds, k=20) 
+ (Visibility, k=3) + Seastate + WindDir, data=df_count, method="REML")
```

The variable visibility is the issue here, I cannot increase the basis functions k any higher than 3 due to unique combinations. I have excluded all surveys with visibility <90%, so now the only values I have in my dataset are 90, 95 and 100%. Here the gam.check() output with visibility k=3

```
> gam.check(gam_Sp1_perc_all) #all sign--> model unstable? NO,because:  

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 10 iterations.
Gradient range [-5.630335e-05,5.578655e-05]
(score 204.5643 & scale 0.2980554).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [4.648033e-05,107.0027].
Model rank =  81 / 81 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                 k'   edf k-index p-value  
s(LunarPerc) 19.00  1.51    0.98   0.370  
s(Duration)   29.00  1.00    1.07   0.830  
s(Clouds)     19.00  1.96    1.08   0.870  
s(Visibility)  2.00  1.00    0.88   0.035 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Visibility has a low p-value but I cannot increase the k-value, anything else I can do? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526858/problem-with-gam-fitting-using-gam-check-to-check-the-basis-dimension-results) they suggest to increase the number of covariates but I think I have enough in the model. The difference between edf and k is not big either, so any suggestions what might be causing this? Or might it be better to add visibility as a linear variable in the model since edf=1?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much point trying to smooth a variable that has only three unique values; the effect would have to depart from non-linearity to a huge degree to be identified against a linear fit.

In situations like this, just fit it as `Visibility` or `poly(Visibility, 2)` for a linear of a quadratic parametric term respectively.

Note the difference between `k'` and `edf` is not that big because it can't be much larger. `k'` is the maximum values possible given the identifiability constraints, and `edf` is as small as is possible given that the smooth has an unpenalized null space (the linear component).